# ANTLR language - Tree not created (EOF - syntax error)

Tags: java, tree, antlr, token, grammar

I have apparently a mistake in the following language definition :

```
grammar Hello;


object  :
ALL* NAME ALL* '{' 
    (ALL* | (ALL* NAME ALL* NAME)* | (ALL* object)*)*
'}' ALL*;

ALL     :
(~('{' | '}' | '"'))+ -> skip;      // All but braces and double quotes

NAME    :
'"' ALL* '"';
```

When I'm trying to read a file or add content directly (with `run.bat Hello object -gui`), the parser give me a **syntax error** :`mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting NAME`.
And I just have a tree with a single node : 'object'.

Here is the Java source :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HelloLexer lexer = new HelloLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("gamemodes.txt"));
    TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(tokenStream);

    System.out.println(lexer.getAllTokens().size());

    parser.setBuildParseTree(true);

    // Tree Creation
    RuleContext tree = parser.object();
    tree.inspect(parser);
}
```

And finally, the file structure (with some spaces/characters anywhere (without braces and double quotes)) :

```
...
"objName"
{
    ...
    "innerObjName1"
    {
        "firstProperty"  "firstResult"
        ...
        "secondProp"     ""
    }

    "innerObjName2"
    {
        "firstProperty"  "firstResult"
        "secondProp"     ""
    }
}
...
```

**NOTE** : I'm on Windows.

Thanks !

Comment: I think you are attempting to create parser rules (rules that start with a lowercase letter, such as the `object` rule) with regex. I don't think antlr can handle that. Parser rules possess much simpler mechanics.

Comment: I saw some examples with regex like syntax (*, +, ?) and in the [official website](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-Subrules)... Btw, if you have an idea to fix my problem, I'm listening to you :)

Comment: Wow, it seems like this is called EBNF, which I didn't even know existed. Very nice to know this. Sadly, though, I can't help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reportAttemptingFullContext` is not an error. It's simply letting you know that ANTLR 4 is using the section of its internal implementation that uses the complete parse context to ensure accuracy. The message is included because the full context algorithm is a bit slower than the SLL algorithm it attempts first.

**Edit:** If you are using a non-standard distribution, you may need to specify the following option to make sure the parse tree is built. This option is true by default in the official distribution.

```
parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
```

**Edit 2:** Covering grammar issues.

Here is the `object` rule from the original grammar with only formatting changes.

```
object // intermediate form 1
    :   ALL* NAME ALL* '{' 
        (   ALL*
        |   (ALL* NAME ALL* NAME)*
        |   (ALL* object)*
        )*
        '}' ALL*
    ;
```

This rule is highly ambiguous. As a quick example, note that the following modified grammar will actually match the same input.

```
object // intermediate form 2
    :   ALL* NAME ALL* '{' 
        (   ALL
        |   ALL* NAME ALL* NAME
        |   ALL* object
        )*
        '}' ALL*
    ;
```

Another simplification removes the Unnecessary `ALL*` prefixes from 2 alts.

```
object // final form
    :   ALL* NAME ALL* '{' 
        (   ALL
        |   NAME ALL* NAME
        |   object
        )*
        '}' ALL*
    ;
```

As a final change, I would create an `entry` rule that ends with an explicit `EOF`:

```
entry : object EOF;
```

To parse your input, call `entry()` instead of `object()` to ensure that all of your input gets parsed. If you need the `ObjectContext` object, it is available by calling `EntryContext.object()`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Good to know it's not an error, but the tree seems to not be generated now (before, I had a different grammar which generates it).. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I've enhanced the topic subject/content to explain my comment better.

Comment: Please read my edit too (I've an error now).. I also added parser.setBuildParseTree(true) but it gives me the same result

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now !! I will give you the bounty when it will be possible (1 hour) :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `skip` a lexer rule, you must not use it in your parser rules.

Try something like this:

```
grammar Hello;

parse
 : object EOF
 ;

object
 : NAME (OBRACE object+ CBRACE | NAME)
 ;

NAME   : '"' ~["{}]* '"';
OBRACE : '{';
CBRACE : '}';
OTHER  : ~["{}]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bart. I didn't know about the `skip`. Btw, the error is still here, at the last line at character 0 : `mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting NAME`..